# Is this RESTful URL (http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweet/id.format)?

Tags: rest, twitter

I've come across a [Twitter REST API Method: statuses retweet](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554741/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3a-statuses-retweet) which they say is RESTful. But I am confused now with the knowledge I have about RESTful API.

Every URI should contain nouns only not actions, but in this URI I think 'retweet' is an action or a verb in a sense. Is this RESTful or am I missing anything or misunderstood this principle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't get too hung up on what a URI looks like but in this case, you can think of a retweet as a Resource and that you are creating a retweet when you POST to that URI. If you also look at other methods there is a "retweets" resource the GETs all the retweets.

Now it would be not considered RESTful style if the web service did something like this:

POST http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses?action=retweet&id=1&format=json, that would be more RPC.

Comment: What about the point every URI should point to existing resource, in this case retweet is not a resource at all. Please correct me if my explanation is wrong.

Comment: Think of it as not a verb. Instead of "I am going to retweet this status", "I am going to add this status to my retweets".